# Messaging system in a website between the users theirselves

Tags: c#, xmpp, messaging

I want to add to my website a messaging system where my logged-in users can message other user (like Facebook, Fiverr..).

Doing it by ourselves is a lot of maintenance and development time we do not have.
Using Layer or SendBird is too expensive for us.
Using Quickblox is not recommended by our friends who used it.

Do you know any other messaging sdk`s for Web , where you can easily intergrate this ability to your website and it contain all the complex messaging options (text, files, group message)?

Comment: Maybe SignalR will work for you.

Comment: Try SignalR or Pubnub

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to keep with sendbird free version: 
 First : - It has really good documentation, which means easy to follow and implement. 
 Second : - It support Javascript which probably your app written by, and react, react native which let you make the web to app/ crossplatform. 
 Third  : -It gives you service support, and sample to follow.

The only problem is that Free version supports up to 1000 users, more than that you need to upgrade.
Here is the link have a look: 
 **https://sendbird.com/pricing**

Answer (score 1):

Just run your own XMPP server and use a Javascript library with BOSH or websockets on you frontend. 
See:
https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html

https://xmpp.org/software/servers.html

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try [spika](http://www.spikaapp.com/), it's open source and seems to fulfill your requirements, including send files and images.